# Herança, polimorfismo e acesso à métodos

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, instanciar-objeto, polimorfismo

Possuo 3 classes e 1 `enum`:

```
public class Pessoa {
        private TipoPessoa tipo;
        public TipoPessoa getTipo() {
            return tipo;
        }
        public void setTipo(TipoPessoa tipo) {
            this.tipo = tipo;
        }
      }



public class PessoaF  extends Pessoa{
                private String cpf;
                public String getCpf() {
                    return cpf;
                }
            public void setCpf(String cpf) {
                this.cpf = cpf;
            }
         }



public class PessoaJ extends Pessoa{
            private String cnpj;
            public String getCnpj() {
                return cnpj;
            }
            public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
                this.cnpj = cnpj;
            }
        }



public enum TipoPessoa {
            PESSOAFISICA, PESSOAJURIDICA;
        }
```

Eu quero que ao setar um tipo de pessoa, consiga criar uma instancia equivalente ao enumerador aplicado no tipo:

Por exemplo, se ao setor uma PESSOAFISICA, eu conseguisse acessar os membros (atributos, campos e métodos) da classe PessoaF, pois ele chamaria o construtor correto:

```
Pessoa p1 = new PessoaF();
p1.setCpf = 32443265332;
```

Porém com herança não consigo acessar os membros de uma classe filha através de uma instancia criada a partir de uma classe pai. Então como proceder?

Modifiquei o enum, implementando um método abstrato que me retorna o construtor que quero utilizar de acordo com o tipo de pessoa setada:

```
public enum TipoPessoa {
    PESSOAFISICA (0, "Pessoa Fisica") {
        @Override
        public Pessoa obterPessoa() {
            return new PessoaF();
        }
    },
    PESSOAJURIDICA (1, "Pessoa Juridica") {
        @Override
        public Pessoa obterPessoa() {
            return new PessoaJ();
        }
    };



    public abstract Pessoa obterPessoa();


    private TipoPessoa(){}
    private TipoPessoa(Integer cod, String desc) {
        this.cod = cod;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    private Integer cod;
    private String desc;
    public Integer getCod() {
        return cod;
    }
    public void setCod(Integer cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
 }
```

com esta modificação estou criando o objeto da seguinte forma:

```
Pessoa p1 = TipoPessoa.PESSOAFISICA.obterPessoa();
```

Quando solicito que ele imprima o tipo do objeto criado ele me fala que criou corretamente:

```
 System.out.println(p1.getClass());
 Retorno : class Pessoas.PessoaF
```

Porém ainda sim não consigo acessar o método `setCpf()` que se encontra dentro da classe `PessoaF`.

Quero criar uma pessoa e de acordo com o valor setado no atributo tipo. E que este objeto criado consiga acessar os membros de acordo com a opção do enumerador selecionado. Como proceder?

[image: Diagrama de classes]

Comment: pode dar um exemplo, sua pergunta não esta muito clara

Comment: Olá, como na imagem. Tenho uma classe Pessoa que tem como filha a classe PessoaFisica, cada uma tem os seus métodos e atributos. Quero que a classe filha quando eu estanciá-la a partir da classe pai consiga ainda ter visibilidade sobre os seus próprios atributos. O que mostra na imagem é justamente isso, não consigo ter visibilidade de nenhum método da classe PessoaFisica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que deseja criar uma [instância](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inst%C3%A2ncia_(classe)) e não uma [estância](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Est%C3%A2ncia).

[Não gosto do termo atributo, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Você pode acessar todos os membros públicos do tipo do objeto naquele momento. Não pode acessar os membros de um tipo que faça parte daquele objeto, mas que não seja o tipo sendo usado naquele momento. Se o tipo é o pai, só pode acessar os membros dele, não pode acessar os membros do tipo filho.

Se você pode garantir que o objeto é do tipo filho pode fazer um *cast*, que é uma conversão de tipo (não necessariamente muda alguma coisa no dado, apenas informa ao compilador que deseja usar um tipo mais especializado. Aí é permitido acessar os membros do tipo filho, e do pai também porque o filho sempre tem tudo o que o pai tem.

Em geral se o *cast* falhar gerará um erro ou o resultado será um nulo. Há casos que o compilador poderá identificar que não é possível e nem deixe compilar.

Neste exemplo não faz muito sentido sentido declarar `p1` como `Pessoa` se sabe que precisa dele como `PessoaFisica`, mas é possível, aí pode escrever:

```
((PessoaFisica)p1).cpf
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Downcast.java).

A performance será pior se não houver nenhuma otimização que o compilador esteja preparado a fazer.

Também dá para fazer com reflexão, mas é absurdamente pior e despropositado.

Só porque uma ferramenta resolve o que você queria não significa que está certo usá-la.

[image: Ferramenta errada para a tarefa - Cavalo dentro de um carro comum]

Comment: Oi Maniero, tudo bem? Corrigi o texto. O objetivo é que a instancia gerada se comporte conforme eu especificar em tempo de execução. Por exemplo: Vou realizar o cadastro de uma pessoa em um banco de dados. Esta pessoa tem o atributo tipo (enum) que posso escolher entre PessoaFisica ou PessoaJuridica. Este enum retorna um construtor de acordo com a opção. Porém não consigo acessar os atributos da  classes filhas. Estou tentando fazer sem o uso de interface esta atividade: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rC296hM-S4g&t=1211s (É uma aula sobre  Strategy).

Comment: Estava convencido que "campo" era usado por quem usa C# e "atributo" por quem usa java. De tal forma que, nas respostas que dou, tenho a preocupação de usar um ou o outro de acordo com a tag associada à pergunta.

Comment: @ramaral eu também estava, fui pesquisando + e mudei. Há quem não concorde ou que não dá a mínima importância. O SOpt tem me servido de inspiração para aprender muita coisa do jeito certo. Não digo q estou conseguindo, mas estou tentando. Preciso tempo pra arrumar tudo o que eu falei em atributo. Por isso eu acho q precisamos de um espaço pra produzir conhecimento canônico de forma mais livre e criativa, sem deixar a bagunça tomar conta. Pena que algumas pessoas q contribuíam nesse sentido sumiram ou participam pouco. Ainda tem alguns q ajudam nessa evolução, até mesmo questionando os erros :)

Comment: @JoséLuizGonzagaNeto Não sei se a é uma boa estratégia (sem intenção de trocadilho :) ), mas com tão pouca informação não posso afirmar nada. Pelo menos não parece que o que precisa no seu exemplo seja um Strategy.

Comment: @Maniero, estava dando uma olhada, vc esta certo quanto ao uso do termo campo, tanto que a própria linguagem assim se refere quando falamos de reflexão, por exemplo: o método getFields(). Nunca tinha me atentado a esta questão.

Comment: Através de estratégia de reflection consigo acessar os campos e métodos que não estão disponíveis, mas não achei prático em uma classe que tenha muitos campos.

Comment: @JoséLuizGonzagaNeto foge de gambiarra, a resposta que você postou e apagou é baseada em uma dica muito ruim e não muito boa. Eu ainda não entendi o que está tentando fazer, mas não parece certo. Procure usar as ferramentas como eles foram criadas para serem usadas. Se realmente precisa fazer diferente, e duvido que precise, não use a ferramenta que te limita. Se que acessar membros do tipo filho use o tipo filho. Se precisa controlar o tipo filho em um tipo que dependa da sua existência então herança não é o mecanismo correto. OOP é difícil e aprender errado é pior que não usar.

Comment: kkkk por isso apaguei, vou seguir desta forma mesmo. instanciar a filha a partir da filha.

Comment: Essa resposta foi um coice de informações úteis :)

Comment: Oi @Maniero, vc esta certo, não adianta ficar inventando meios que na frente podem gerar algum tipo de prejuízo e retrabalho, agradeço a sinceridade.

Comment: *"Ainda tem alguns q ajudam nessa evolução, até mesmo questionando os erros"* - Os revisores têm um papel muito importante no processo de "produção de conhecimento" :)